# I want multiple SoundCloud widgets to play simultaneously on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, soundcloud

I have two soundcloud widgets hidden on my page. I have linked them to divs that act as play buttons. Currently, when the first div is clicked, the first sound starts. When the second div is clicked, the second sound starts and the first sound is automatically paused. I want the sounds to play simultaneously.

```
<div id = "bgSound">
  <iframe id = 'first' width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/257485031?secret_token=s-i9opu&color=ff5500&inverse=false&auto_play=false&show_user=true"></iframe>

  <iframe id = "second" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/257498359?secret_token=s-c9D5D&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true"></iframe>
</div>
```

```
var widget1 = SC.Widget('first'); 
var widget2 = SC.Widget('second')
$('.Top-Left').click(function() {
    widget1.play();
});
$('.Top-Center').click(function() {
    widget2.play();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `single_active=false` to ensure both can play at the same time, otherwise one will pause the other when it starts playing.

```
<div id = "bgSound">
  <iframe id="first" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/257485031?secret_token=s-i9opu&color=ff5500&inverse=false&auto_play=false&show_user=true&single_active=false"></iframe>

  <iframe id="second" width="0" height="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/257498359?secret_token=s-c9D5D&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true&single_active=false"></iframe>
</div>
```

```
var widget1 = SC.Widget('first'); 
var widget2 = SC.Widget('second')
$('.Top-Left').click(function() {
    widget1.play();
});
$('.Top-Center').click(function() {
    widget2.play();
});
```

[SoundCloud Widget Parameter Documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget#parameters)